# unable to install neo4j-python on jython2.5.1 : keyError 'project.artifactId'

Tags: python, linux

I have this error: KeyError: 'project.artifactId'

```
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server/neo4j-python$ ../jython2.5.1/jython setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 146, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 134, in main
    args[attr] = pom[attr]
  File "/hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 57, in __getitem__
    return self.pattern.sub(lambda match:self[match.groupdict()['var']],
  File "/hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return self.pattern.sub(lambda match:self[match.groupdict()['var']],
  File "/hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    element = self.parent[path]
  File "/hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    return replacement.get(path, lambda s,x:x)(self, self.__pom[path])
  File "/hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(path)
KeyError: 'project.artifactId'
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server/neo4j-python$
```

My configuration for jython is as follows:

```
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server$ jython2.5.1/bin/jython -V
Jython 2.5.1
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server$ jython2.5.1/bin/jython -v
import: 'exceptions' as org.python.core.exceptions in builtin modules
import: import os # precompiled from /hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/jython2.5.1/Lib/os$py.class
import: 'errno' as org.python.modules.errno in builtin modules
import: 'jarray' as org.python.modules.jarray in builtin modules
import: 'java' as java package
import: 'System' as java class
import: 'time' as org.python.modules.time.Time in builtin modules
import: import stat # precompiled from /hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/jython2.5.1/Lib/stat$py.class
import: 'sys' as sys in builtin modules
import: 'File' as java class
import: 'org' as java package
import: 'FileDescriptors' as java class
import: 'FileIO' as java class
import: 'IOBase' as java class
import: 'Py' as java class
import: 'Errno' as java class
import: 'JavaPOSIX' as java class
import: 'POSIXHandler' as java class
import: 'POSIXFactory' as java class
import: import posixpath # precompiled from /hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/jython2.5.1/Lib/posixpath$py.class
import: 'IOException' as java class
import: 'SecureRandom' as java class
import: 'FileDescriptor' as java class
Jython 2.5.1 (Release_2_5_1:6813, Sep 26 2009, 13:47:54)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Sun Microsystems Inc.)] on java1.6.0_22
import: import site # precompiled from /hpcdrive/homes/admmarc/neo4j-server/jython2.5.1/Lib/site$py.class
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> quit()
```

I have setuptools installed.
By now, all the components are on userspace:

```
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server/neo4j-python$ ls -at ..
.  neo4j-python  ..  jython2.5.1  jdk1.6.0_23  neo4j-1.2  neo4j-1.2-unix.tar.gz  ez_setup.py  jdk-6u23-linux-x64.bin  jython_installer-2.5.1.jar
admmarc@fbmgrid01:~/neo4j-server/neo4j-python$
```

The box is an Ubuntu 9.10 x64.

And this is it, any help will be welcome, as questions will also be very welcome. I can do almost whatever test is needed to be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [solution](http://sake.in.th/blog/%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A5%E0%B8%87-neo4j-python-%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%99-ubuntu-1004), edit pom.py:

```
if element is None: # added
    element = self.tree.findtext(self.__path('dependencies')) # added
if element is None:
    raise KeyError(path)
```